The VMA and LMA in the section of the GCC link file are different, resulting in function exceptions
I used a Cortex-M4 chip similar to STM32, and now I want to place some frequently used functions in the fast Flash area, so I wrote the following code:
  .flash_zw0 : ALIGN(4)
  {
    *(.flash_ex)
  } >FAST_FLASH AT> FLASH

After compilation, I saw that the functions in the. map file were stored according to the specified section, but when the program ran to the functions in that section, it would enter a hardfault。
When I am not using AT>:
  .flash_zw0 : ALIGN(4)
  {
    *(.flash_ex)
  } >FAST_FLASH

There won't be any issues with the program.
So I think the difference between VMA and LMA can cause program exceptions, but I don't know the reason and solution. The addresses of these two regions in memory are far apart, and I must map them, otherwise the generated bin file will be too large to upgrade.
This is the other part of my script file:
MEMORY
{
FAST_FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08014000, LENGTH = 48k
FAST_FLASH_1 (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08020000, LENGTH = 128k
FLASH_0 (irx)   : ORIGIN = 0x0807f800, LENGTH = 2k
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08080000, LENGTH = 512K
RAM (xrw)       : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 96K
}

I hope to map the FAST_FLASH virtual memory address(VML) to the FLASH Load Memory Address(LMA).
Actually, whenever I use AT> for address mapping, the function will have problems.
Besides, my English is not very good:)

Welcome to SO. What do you want to achieve with AT > FLASH?

Reduce the size of the generated .bin file to avoid creating too many blank gaps

No, I meant what should be the effect on the created sections? Do you want to create a section with addresses of FAST_FLASH and place it into FLASH area? You mention different VMA and LMA. You should add what all the involved resulting addresses are.

Corresponding explanations have been added to the original text.

I am not familiar with M4, only with M0+ and M23. Are yo sure you have virtual addresses? For me, it looks like you tell everyon the functions are at 0x08014000 but instead they are located at 0x08080000 and the FAST_FLASH area is just empty. Why do you care about gaps in .bin file? Could you use hex file?

I might be mistaken, but I believe you don't need the AT part. The fast flash isn't volatile right? So you shouldn't need to store the code elsewhere. If you use the AT keyword, it means that you have to relocate the code from flash to fast flash at some point, either in your startup file or beginning of your c code.

you are right,I didn't relocate the code from flash to fast flash at some point Causing problems,thank you.
